# Optimizar y orden

Tags: python, diccionarios, pycharm

Hola quisiera si hay otra manera de agregar más eficiente de agregar diccionarios a una lista.

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro ": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro ": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro ": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro ": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro ": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": " saturno", "diametro ": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": " urano", "diametro ": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro ": 49.500}


lista = []
lista.append(mercurio)
lista.append(venus)
lista.append(tierra)
lista.append(marte)
lista.append(jupiter)
lista.append(urano)
lista.append(neptuno)
print(lista)
```

Cuando imprime, imprime así: [{'planeta': 'mercurio ', 'diametro ': 4.878}, {'planeta': 'venus', 'diametro ': 12.104}, {'planeta': 'tierra', 'diametro ': 12.756}, {'planeta': 'marte ', 'diametro ': 6.794}, {'planeta': 'jupiter', 'diametro ': 142.8}, {'planeta': ' urano', 'diametro ': 51.8}, {'planeta': 'neptuno', 'diametro ': 49.5}]
y yo deseo que se imprima así:

```
[{'planeta': 'mercurio ', 'diametro ': 4.878},
 {'planeta': 'venus', 'diametro ': 12.104}, 
{'planeta': 'tierra', 'diametro ': 12.756}, 
{'planeta': 'marte ', 'diametro ': 6.794}, 
{'planeta': 'jupiter', 'diametro ': 142.8},
 {'planeta': ' urano', 'diametro ': 51.8},
 {'planeta': 'neptuno', 'diametro ': 49.5}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente ejemplo no es más eficiente en cuanto a velocidad de ejecución (que es similar), pero sí es más compacto y quizás hasta más fácil de leer. Evita la creación de todas esas variables intermedias y sobre todo, es más fácil de extender o adaptar a otros casos similares:

```
lista = []
for nombre, diametro in [("mercurio", 4.878), ("venus", 12.104), ("tierra", 12.756),
                         ("marte", 6.794), ("jupiter", 142.800), ("saturno", 120.660), 
                         ("urano", 51.8), ("neptuno", 49.5)]:
    lista.append({"planeta": nombre, "diametro": diametro})
```

## Otra posibilidad

Si tienes separadamente una lista con los nombres y otra con los diámetros, la función `zip()` es muy útil para ir obteniendo pares de elementos, cada uno tomado de cada una de esas listas. Así:

```
nombres = ['mercurio', 'venus', 'tierra', 'marte', 'jupiter', 'saturno', 'urano', 'neptuno']
diametros = [4.878, 12.104, 12.756, 6.794, 142.8, 120.66, 51.8, 49.5]

lista = []
for nombre, diametro in zip(nombres, diametros):
  lista.append({"planeta": nombre, "diametro": diametro})
```

Answer (score 1):

la forma en la que agregas diccionarios a la lista es correcta, para imprimirlos mas ordenados podrias  iterar manualmente entre los elementos:

```
for mes in lista:
    print(mes)
```

salida

```
 {'planeta': 'mercurio ', 'diametro ': 4.878},
 {'planeta': 'venus', 'diametro ': 12.104}, 
 {'planeta': 'tierra', 'diametro ': 12.756}, 
 {'planeta': 'marte ', 'diametro ': 6.794}, 
 {'planeta': 'jupiter', 'diametro ': 142.8},
 {'planeta': ' urano', 'diametro ': 51.8},
 {'planeta': 'neptuno', 'diametro ': 49.5}
```

O utilizar la librería estándar `json` para mostrarlo de manera más ordenada (te recomiendo usar esta):

```
import json

print(json.dumps(lista, indent=4))
```

salida

```
[
    {
        "planeta": "mercurio ",
        "diametro ": 4.878
    },
    {
        "planeta": "venus",
        "diametro ": 12.104
    },
    {"planeta": "tierra",
        "diametro ": 12.756
    },
    {
        "planeta": "marte ",
        "diametro ": 6.794
    },
    {
        "planeta": "jupiter",
        "diametro ": 142.8
    },
    {
        "planeta": " urano",
        "diametro ": 51.8
    },
    {
        "planeta": "neptuno",
        "diametro ": 49.5
    }
]
```

el parametro `indent=4` es para decidir los espacios de indentación de los distinton niveles.

Saludos!